# Abstract class in Java with global variables aren't setting?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I've got 2 classes setup, both extending a Module class. I'm trying to set 2 integers in one of them and using 2 integers in the other.
However when I execute everything, it does get set (I know because of debugging) but when the method for 'printing' runs, it's still 0.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong though.

Module Class:

```
public abstract class Module {
     protected int min, max;
}
```

Foo1:

```
public class Foo1 extends Module {
     public void setMinMax(){
         min = 2;
         max = 5;
     }
}
```

Foo2:

```
public class Foo2 extends Module {
     public void printMinMax(){
         System.out.print("Min: " + min + " Max: " + max);
     }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "global variables"? In your code It is natural that `setMinMax()` won't affect `printMinMax()` because no single instance can have both of the methods because they are in separate classes.

Comment: The problem is your understanding of java / oop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set one instance, it has no effect on another instance.  Each instance has it's own fields.  Most likely what you imagined was

```
public abstract class Module {
     protected static int min, max;
}
```

This way the fields will be shared between all instances of `Module`.  You should only set these field from a static method, ideally on `Module`

However, I would avoid doing this, or using mutable static fields whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 instances of 2 different classes. One instance of a `Foo1`, with its own `min`/`max`, and one instance of a `Foo2`, *again* with its own `min`/`max`.

Note that your `Foo` class provides the fields, and each time you instantiate a derived instance (of `Foo1` or `Foo2`), you'll get a new class with a new set of fields (including those derived from the base class)